# Activeadmin RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, friendly-id

After setting up the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem, I've faced a problem with the [activeadmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem,
whereby it throws `RecordNotFound` whenever I'm trying to update, delete or create Posts using admin panel.

Here is the code from *app/controllers/post_controller.rb*:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And from app/models/post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :title, :slug, :blurb, :content, :category_id
  scope :tarot, -> { where(category_id: 1) }
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

Comment: error stack trace? You can get it from the log file.

Comment: Any more info would be appreciated. Did you drop and migrate the database? Have the table got slug column? Is the friendly-id has created in that column. I think the `extend FriendlyId` part should be on the first row of the class definition.

Comment: yes, the table has a slug column.

Answer (score 1):

The moment was in the app/models/post.rb:

```
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

which should be:

```
friendly_id :title, use: :[slugged, :finders]
```